# Getting TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'#' on including a Mustache template in html file served by python Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, mustache, client-side-templating

I am getting a `TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'#'` error, when I include a simple Mustache template in my HTML file being served by Python Google App Engine server.

The mustache template that I want to include is:

> {{#item}}
>   {{name}}
>   {{/item}}

My HTML file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/mustache-template" id="myTemplate">
      {{#item}}{{name}}{{/item}}
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Since, the template is wrapped around a script tag with type=text/mustache-template, shouldn't the server just ignore it?

I am unable to comprehend, why am I getting the TemplateSyntaxError and what should I do to get rid of it.
Anyone has any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: You haven't said if the error is being generated by javascript or on the backend. Are you using a server based templating system as well, in which case stuff inside the script tags is usually processed as well, depending on the template system.

Comment: The error is being generated on the backend. I am using Jinja2 templates on the server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't say so, but I guess you are using either Django or Jinja2 templates on the server side. In which case, no they wouldn't ignore content inside a mustache script tag: for one thing, they know nothing about mustache, and secondly it's fairly common practice to actually put server-side template tags inside Javascript, for instance to provide initial values for functions.

In Django versions greater than 1.5, you can wrap your mustache tags with the `{% verbatim %}...{% endverbatim %}` tag to prevent server-side evaluation. Jinja2's equivalent is  `{% raw %}...{% endraw %}`.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Jinja2 templates on the server side. Adding the raw tags work!

Comment: While i want to render with the variable which was started with invalid chars? how to keep the template in original one?