# jinja2 throwing TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char

Tags: python, templates, dictionary, jinja2

I am passing Jinja a dataset that includes time-bucket strings like "0Y-5Y". The tags are standard to my organization, so I prefer not to change them. However, the string is causing Jinja to throw a `TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char` error.

**Can someone please explain why this particular error arises, and how I can get around it?**

I see [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190948/templatesyntaxerror-unexpected-char-u-at-205-airflow-macros) that variables with space characters might throw similar error, but that does not apply in my case.

It seems almost like Jinja is trying to parse the string as a number? I thought it was just a simple string used as the dictionary key? Is there a way to force Jinja not to do this, like with [raw tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932888/getting-templatesyntaxerror-unexpected-char-u-on-including-a-mustache-templa) or similar?

Here is my code:

```
# https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-jinja-templating/#flask-examples
from jinja2 import Template

data = [
         {'name':'aaa','0Y-5Y':100,'5Y-25Y':50,'total':150}
        ,{'name':'bbb','0Y-5Y':10,'5Y-25Y':125,'total':135}
    ]

html_ok = """
{% for item in data %}
  {{ item.name }} {{ item.total }}
{% endfor %}
"""

html_error = """
{% for item in data %}
  {{ item.name }} {{ item.0Y-5Y }}
{% endfor %}
"""

t=Template(html_ok)
print t.render( data=data )

t=Template(html_error)
print t.render( data=data )
```

And the output:

```
  aaa 150

  bbb 135


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\beRto\Desktop\jinja_number_key.py", line 23, in <module>
    t=Template(html_error)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.9.5-py2.7.egg\jinja2\environment.py", line 945, in __new__
    return env.from_string(source, template_class=cls)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.9.5-py2.7.egg\jinja2\environment.py", line 880, in from_string
    return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.9.5-py2.7.egg\jinja2\environment.py", line 591, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.9.5-py2.7.egg\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<unknown>", line 3, in template
TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char u'Y' at 51
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `item['0Y-5Y']` instead of `item.0Y-5Y` as you are accesing the cells in your data like:

```
html_ok = """
{% for item in data %}
  {{ item['name'] }}  {{ item['0Y-5Y'] }}
{% endfor %}
 """
```

Comment: I had no idea that syntax was valid. I'll have to look into it a little more, but it worked with the toy program presented above. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: I think it cannot just parse **item.0Y-5Y**. Try to define a variable in Python, like `0Y-5Y` or even `0Y5Y`, they fail. A variable/Attribute begining with 0 and a minus sign in it too? It won't like it ;)